# Find all paths without specifing end node?

Tags: python, graph

I'm trying to do a Depth First search to find a list of all paths and then identify the shortest and longest paths.

The python documentation (https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/)  has the following, which requires an end node:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

My question is how can I find all paths in a (directed acyclic) graph without specifying the end node? My start node would remain the same at all times.

I could use a for loop at the start and iterate through the nodes. but this doesn't feel like the most efficient way of doing so because if I could be using the same path to revisit a node which would be a waste of compute time.

```
for node in nodeList:
    find_all_paths(graph, 0, node)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your depth-first search code can be modified to find all paths to all end nodes with just a few tweaks.

First, drop the `end` parameter, and the base case where `start == end`. Then, simply add `path` to `paths` before starting the recursive steps. In the recursive call, don't try to pass `end` any more.

That's it:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return [path]
    paths = [path]
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

Note that you can do this a bit more efficiently as a recursive generator, rather than building up a big list of paths (I've also modified the special check for a node not in the graph: using the `not in` operator is better than using `dict.has_key`):

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    yield path
    if start not in graph:
        return
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            yield from find_all_paths(graph, node, path)
```

Note that `yield from` is only available in Python 3.3 and later. If you're using an earlier version, use an explicit loop:

```
for newpath in find_all_paths(graph, node, path):
    yield newpath
```